# Launch an openstack instance with single NIC

Tags: networking, bridge, openstack, nova-network

I'm totally new to openstack and without much resources I built a cloud with my pc as controller containing a wifi for internet and ethernet for internal connection also with my laptop again with a wifi and ethernet. Everything seems to be fine and I have an active instance but it has no network:

```
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+----------+ 
| ID                                   | Name | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+----------+ 
| 703c1663-5a1d-47c9-a9a8-466f75d5c802 | Ins1 | ACTIVE | -          | Running     |          |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

I'm using nova-network(Legacy) and I know I should create a network using `nova network create` and a bridge but I only have one interface on every node(ethernet) and was wondering what to do. Can anybody help?

BTW: Can a network node help?
I have a raspberry pi that could be one.

AND: when I setup a bridge on controller, compute node loses access to it.
help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set this up at home with two pc's, one for the controller, one for the compute node. Both have 2 NIC's. 1 NIC on each PC is "public" (i.e. my home network), the second set of NIC's I used for a peer-to-peer connection between both PC's as the "management" network. Since you have two network connection on both of your devices, you could try with the WLAN facing the "public" network, and the NIC's being the "management" network.

These are my configuration files (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

ON COMPUTE1
Install metadata service

```
apt-get install nova-network nova-api-metadata
```

Edit configuration of eth0 (the external interface in my case; probably WLAN in your case) in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    up ip link set dev $IFACE up
    down ip link set dev $IFACE down
```

Apply the network changes.

Edit nova.conf to define the networking mode.
Change flat_interface and public_interface to suit your setup.

```
[DEFAULT]
...
network_manager=nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
firewall_driver=nova.virt.libvirt.firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
network_size=254
allow_same_net_traffic=False
multi_host=True
send_arp_for_ha=True
share_dhcp_address=True
force_dhcp_release=True
flat_network_bridge=br100
flat_interface=eth0
public_interface=eth0


service nova-network restart
```

ON CONTROLLER:

Create a network that virtual machines can use

```
source keystone.rc # If you have a file with the correct environment settings

nova network-create vmnet \
--fixed-range-v4=192.168.63.0/24 \
--bridge-interface=br100 \
--multi-host=T
```

check (controller)

```
nova network-list
```

This is a rather straightforward copy/paste of what I did to get it working. Hopefully it gives you some inspiration/ideas to adapt to your own case.

Comment: tnx, so I shouldn't setup br100 myself and nova sets it up for me?

Comment: That's how it worked for me